# Android - DialogFragment xml getting cut

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I have a problem in my dialog fragment. For some reason when it opens the dialog fragment it cut the textView,spiner and the buttons. in other words it cut all the right side.

[image: Dialog Fragment]
as you can see, all the right side is cut off.
in the android studio it is look fine, but when i run it, this what happens.
how can i fix it?

**This is XML code**

```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.world.bolandian.talent.fragments.AddVideoAudioFragment">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="UPLOAD YOUR MUSIC"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="227dp"
    android:layout_height="19dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:entries="@color/bootstrap_brand_info"
    android:popupBackground="@color/bootstrap_brand_success"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:text="Choose Genre"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInPut"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/etTitleMusic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Title your upload" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


<com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
    android:id="@+id/btnUploadVideo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:text="UPLOAD VIDEO"
    app:bootstrapBrand="primary"
    app:bootstrapSize="lg"
    app:buttonMode="regular"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInPut"
    app:roundedCorners="true"
    app:showOutline="false" />

<com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
    android:id="@+id/btnUploadAudio"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="UPLOAD AUDIO"
    app:bootstrapBrand="warning"
    app:bootstrapSize="lg"
    app:buttonMode="regular"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnUploadVideo"
    app:roundedCorners="true"
    app:showOutline="false" />
```

Comment: I was facing some similar issue. Had to shift back to LinearLayout. Did you try that?

Comment: Change your root layout to similar layouts like LinearLayout.